# How to get 'noticed' to possibly become a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm a pretty avid user of SU. However, I spend most of my time there rather than here in the meta discussions.

I would be very willing and happy to become a moderator there to help even more, but I feel that lack of 'meta activity' would hinder that chance.

This isn't a cry for me to become a moderator, but just a general question as to how one can be 'noticed' if they aren't heavy meta users?

Comment: (1) use meta more; (2) make good jokes (or bad ones that people like); (3) help out LOTS on the site; (4) never ask about how to become a mod; (5) get suckered into [giving up your ~](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44145/a-last-tribute-to-the-tilde)

Comment: To clarify @quack's comment: Basically it boils down to "Never ask to become a mod".. So yea, I'd give up now that you've asked ;) Also, you only have 3k rep. Ask again when you have 10k

Comment: @quack: maybe I just missed out on a meme, but what does your fifth point (about tildes) mean?

Comment: According to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43378/should-random-be-elected-a-moderator-on-super-user) all you need to do is start using up all your flags every day, that's how @random did it :)

Answer (score 8):

Use what abilities you have.  Right now you can vote to close/reopen, edit, and retag.  Do those things effectively and people will start to notice.  You can also flag things for moderator attention to get noticed by the current mods.

**Note:** Do these things poorly and you'll naturally be shooting yourself in the foot.

You'll also want to keep asking/answering questions to get your rep up to the 10k level so you can start using *those* tools.

Basically, just be as generally helpful on SU as possible.

Comment: also: be polite. and taking the time to explain to new users (in comments) how to use the site properly always helps.

Comment: @quack: Definitely!  I know a few people who post simple "This should be a separate question, blah, blah blah,... Welcome to SO." comments, and that really sticks out in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

Create or become a meme, it's a sure fire way.

But jokes aside, just be consistent, friendly and helpful. The main thing is that you're there, a lot. If people can think "Hey, this is a great question for X, because he helped me in the past" then you're on your way.

Another thing. Mod != High rep user. A mod is a person that can be counted on to be there and can be trusted to do their job. So having a history of being awesome helps a lot.

Comment: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: ~ indeed ~ indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Being active on SU is more likely to get you noticed than being active on MSO. There are relatively few of us that spend any real time here, and everyone gets just one vote for a moderator.

Answer (score 1):

Put a beaver on your avatar.

Comment: Any cartoon animal really helps.

Comment: @Bill, can we please exclude computer-generated unicorns from that category?  I think we've seen enough of those to last a lifetime.

Comment: @aaro: oy.  i can only hope...

Comment: Actually, ponies.

Comment: ah yes, but Canada is removing the beavers.. http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/8528672.stm

Answer (score 0):

I hear that Jeff likes waffles.. Figure out his address and send him some waffles. Bribing is **always** the way to go

Comment: -1 to put my reputation at 666 - muhahaha...

Comment: I endorse this downvote :) lol